# How to provide a validation check for inputting the right file path (remote or local server) in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a form that should accept a file path (directory) if it's within a valid format (regardless of it being in a remote/local server i.e FTP) and does not contain any specific files i.e **<'file_directory'>\pic.png'**. If the path is not valid, it should not save it into the model.

I have tried the following:

**views.py:**

```
from pathlib import Path as PATH  #using pathlib since it's used on all OS platforms.

def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid():  
            user_id = request.user.id  
            folder_path = form.cleaned_data['folder_path']

            path = PATH(folder_path)  #using pathlib module to check if the folder_path exists.
            root, extension = os.path.splitext(folder_path)  #checks if extension is seen in folder_path.
            if extension or not path.resolve(strict=True): 
                messages.warning(request, "Path is not valid.")
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                #save the path to the model
    else:
        form = PForm()
    return render(request, 'template/home.html, {'form' : form})
```

The validation for checking file extensions work but once I enter an invalid directory path, I am getting this error:

```
Exception Type: FileNotFoundError
Exception Value: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '<invalid pathname>'  #eg 'var/html/www/pictures'
```

How can I implement a better validation check and a way to handle the errors? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use a `try except` statement. Handle `FileNotFoundError ` in the `except`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture the exceptions and handle accordingly as below.

```
try:
    path = PATH(folder_path)
    root, extension = os.path.splitext(folder_path)
    ....
# capture exceptions here (you can add multiple)
except FileNotFoundError:
    # handle exceptions as needed here
    messages.warning(request, "Path is not valid.")
    return redirect('home')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: Just like to know something, is this possible for any path in a server? Suppose if I had a path in my server called : **'var/html/www/pictures/'**. Will it be able to recognize and stop invalid paths from being saved in my model?